# Can I create Bitmaps with the Android NDK in C++ and pass them to Java really fast?

Tags: java, android, c++, bitmap

I need to create Bitmaps in C++ with the ndk and pass them to Java. I don't mean copy but actually pass them as a parameter or return value or anything else like that because copying them would be far too slow. I also really need to create them in the NDK part and not in java.

Does anyone know a way to do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Peter Lawrey already pointed out using a non-Java object is not possible however it may be possible to directly paint the raw data from a simple Java byte array (which can be directly accessed on the C++ side).

In the end you could even call [Canvas.drawBitmap(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) using this byte array for painting your created image. Of course that requires to store the image on C++ side directly in the required format inside the byte array.

Java:

```
byte[] pixelBuf = new byte[bufSize];
```

Then pass the `byte[]` reference to the native C++ implementation. On C++ side you can call

C++:

```
jbyte* pixelBufPtr = env->GetByteArrayElements(pixelBuf, JNI_FALSE);
jsize pixelBufLen = env->GetArrayLength(env, pixelBuf);
// modify the data at pixelBufPtr with C++ functions
env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(pixelBuf, pixelBufPtr, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do I understand you right that the byte array has to be completely created in java and then can only be accessed and changed in c++ ?

Comment: Yes, you have to create the byte array in Java. On C++ side you can "lock" the data for getting the pointer. After unlocking you can use and change it in Java, too. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a direct ByteBuffer.  A ByteBuffer referes to a native area of memory.  However to use the Image in Java it has to be in a Java object.  You can assemble this object in Java or C, but I don't see how you can avoid copying the image unless your C library writes the image as the Java structure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My goal is to allocate bitmaps beyond the java heap memory which means it has to be allocated in c++. Is there a way to somehow achieve this with the byte buffer ?

Comment: You can change the address field of the ByteBuffer to point where ever you like from JNI (or reflection)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my solution was to allocate the huge buffer in C++ and then draw each requested "view" into a Java bitmap. I use the "new" NDK bitmap functions which showed up in Android 2.2; they allow direct access to the bitmap bits. It may not be ideal for your use, but it does avoid copying bitmaps and allow you to create bitmaps as large as free memory. I create a bitmap the size of the display window and then draw scaled views from the large bitmap into it with my own native code scaler.

Comment: BitBank: did you get the bitmap draw code from an online sample?  If so, could you post a link to it?

Comment: The bitmap draw code is my own (ARM asm) and I would rather not post it.